# Reinstall DirectX9 dll in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, dll, directx, directx-9

I'm trying to run League of Legends on a Windows 10 x64 computer. I can launch the main screen, but when I try to start an actual game, it fails with a message stating:

> **System Error**
>
> The program can't start because d3dx9_39.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I've tried reinstalling both League of Legends **and** DirectX9 (from the [DirectX End-User Runtime Web Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35)), but both of them say DirectX9 is already installed and won't change a thing.

I don't find any option to uninstall DirectX from the Control Panel.

Funny thing is - I see a `d3dx9_39.dll` file in both `C:\Windows\System32\d3dx9_39.dll` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3dx9_39.dll`.

**How can I reinstall the missing DirectX9 components?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was simple, albeit ugly - delete/rename the problematic dlls.

I've **renamed both `d3dx9_39.dll` files** (in both `C:\Windows\System32\d3dx9_39.dll` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3dx9_39.dll`) to something like `__d3dx9_39.dll`, **and re-ran the DirectX9 Runtime Web Installer**. Since there's now no file called `d3dx9_39.dll`, the Web Installer will happily download them from the internet and install them from scratch.

Deleting the files (instead of renaming them) works the same, but I wanted to keep copies around just in case.